# Running timer task at 0200 hrs everyday

Tags: java, timer, ejb

I have a timer ejb that controls when the application runs that needs to be switched. I need to make it to run at 0200 hrs everyday

```
public void fireInTwentyFourHours() throws EJBException  
      TimerService theTimerService = mySessionCtx.getTimerService();
      String aLabel = "24 Hours Interval";
      //theTimerService.createTimer(new Date(),86400000, aLabel);
      String stage = Stage.getStage();
      List timerObjects = (List)theTimerService.getTimers();
      if(null != timerObjects && timerObjects.size() > 0) {
        for(int timerCount=0,size=timerObjects.size();timerCount<size;timerCount++) {
            Timer timer = (Timer)timerObjects.get(timerCount);
                timer.cancel();
        }
      }
      if(stage.equalsIgnoreCase("P")){
        theTimerService.createTimer(getRunTime(),86400000, aLabel);
      } else {
        theTimerService.createTimer(new Date(),86400000, aLabel);
      }
    } 

    private Date getRunTime() {
        Calendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        int year = gc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = gc.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int date = gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Calendar newDate = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,date,17,30,0);
        return newDate.getTime();
    }
```

I need to create a new method and make f`ireInTwentyFourHours` to execute at 0200 hrs.

Is this the correct way to make it fire at 0200

```
public Date getTime(){
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  Date d = c.getTime();
  return d;

}

    public void fireInTwentyFourHours() throws EJBException  
              TimerService theTimerService = mySessionCtx.getTimerService();
              String aLabel = "24 Hours Interval";
              //theTimerService.createTimer(new Date(),86400000, aLabel);
              String stage = Stage.getStage();
              List timerObjects = (List)theTimerService.getTimers();
              if(null != timerObjects && timerObjects.size() > 0) {
                for(int timerCount=0,size=timerObjects.size();timerCount<size;timerCount++) {
                    Timer timer = (Timer)timerObjects.get(timerCount);
                        timer.cancel();
                }
              }
              if(stage.equalsIgnoreCase("P")){
                theTimerService.createIntervalTimer(getTime(),86400000, aLabel);
              } else {
                theTimerService.createIntervalTimer(new Date(),86400000, aLabel);
              }
            }
```

the third parameter is timerConfig how to set that. will it make the code to run at 0200?

Comment: convert a Calendar to a Date and use http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html#createTimer(java.util.Date, java.io.Serializable)

Comment: @ScaryWombat i have added a code to make it run at 0200. but how to set the timerconfig as the third parameter in the method createIntervalTimer